# Testing Google Invisible reCAPTCHA v2

Tags: testing, google-chrome-devtools, recaptcha, googlebot, invisible-recaptcha

I am looking for a way to test Google's Invisible reCAPTCHA product.

I am using v2 (not the most recent v3) and I would like to be able to see the reCAPTCHA challenges, however the previously tried-and-tested ways of doing that don't appear to be valid any longer.

Previously I would use the Chrome DevTools to change the User Agent to `Googlebot` and then the reCAPTCHA challenge would display. However, i've read comments that this no longer works.

I have tried using a Edge browser in BrowserStack, but that let the form submission through fine without showing the challenge.

I've had a look on Google's reCAPTCHA docs, but I can't see a recommended way to test this.

The little blue reCAPTCHA box displays statically positioned in the bottom right hand corner of my page and there's no errors in the logs but i'd like to see the reCAPTCHA working to stop bots.

Comment: Here's a [reCAPTCHA developer's guide](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro) with links to a [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/recaptcha) and a [codelab](https://g.co/recaptcha/codelab). Is there any helpful information in any of these links?